# Stuck with getting data from Moz Bar using selenium-python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get spam score from Moz bar using Selenium WebDriver, I tried many ways using XPath, class, and tag name but I couldn't get data. Could you please help?:
[image: Text]

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver as UC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://ifada.net/")

spam_score = driver.find_element_by_class_name('line')
print(spam_score)

driver.close()
```

Moz bar extension URL: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mozbar/eakacpaijcpapndcfffdgphdiccmpknp

Answer (score 1):

`spam_score` is a WebElement, in fact

```
>>> type(spam_score)
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
```

To print the text content of a WebElement you can use `.text` or `.get_attribute('innerText')`. In some cases, for example when the element is not visible in the browser, then you must use `.get_attribute('innerText')`.

In your case notice that there is more than one element with the class `line`, in fact if you run `spam_score = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('line')` (notice the `s` after `element`) you get a list of two elements, i.e. `len(spam_score) = 2`.

To specifically target the score, you have to open the browser inspector tool and look at the HTML code of the webpage, then select the spam score with the mouse. You will see that `<p class="line"></p>` is contained in `<div class="score">`, so to target the spam score you can do `spam_score = driver.find_element_by_class_name('score .line')`, and to print the text content do `spam_score.text` or `spam_score.get_attribute('innerText')`.

```
>>> spam_score.text
'1%'
```